# More text for transparency vs. cleaner design

Tags: simplicity, newsletter, overlay

**Topic:**
Make user sign up for newsletter in an online fashion shop.

**Problem:**
I want to be as **transparent** as possible with the users and not give them the feeling that this is just to grab their data.
The problem is that to be more transparent you have to **add more text**, which in turn **clutters** the already somewhat **annoying view** for the user.

---

**Mockups:**
Keep in mind that the text is placeholder like, it will be fine-tuned later. Also, in my country the checkbox text **has to be that long**, so I kept it that way here.

**Dialog with as little text as possible:**

[image]

**Dialog with additional text** to make the user less scared of the newsletter:

[image]

---

**Question:**
Is it favorable to **give up some "cleanness" for the sake of transparency?** Or maybe the user won't even care at all and only get more annoyed by the additional text.

Comment: If your newsletters have valuable content, show them to users before they sign up. You're asking the user to give you their email address without knowing what they're getting. Show them an old newsletter. That gives you more transparency and a cleaner design on your dialog.

Comment: what @moot said. And do not be afraid to inform users, I've done many tests where more information exceeds the benefits of a cleaner layout (of course, within logical limits, as in your case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's preferable to decrease the visual excise by deleting this 3 lines-sentence under the submit button, since it doesn't inform the user that much.
What you can do is to combine the first subtitle with your sentence at the bottom, e.g. *"by registering for our weekly newsletter"* or something in this way.

Comment: Yeah I think your answer in combination with @moot's comment is what I will do

Answer (score 1):

signing up for newsletters is a tricky thing on the first place. 
keep it clean and simple, use less words. remove "by registering for our newsletter" and read it again. Ask yourself if you really need it. Do you still understand what you are saying without it?
i would also add a "cancel" button. use human language and call it "thanks, not now", "later"

great example of using transparency by specifying the # of newsletters that will be sent + the topics...awesome but would these topics be specific enough to narrow it down or be confusing. will these topics interest your audience or not. overall, it might be too much text for a modal.

let your users sing up and then decide to easily unsubscribe if they choose to.

Comment: but if they don't know it is for the newsletter, what would users be signing to? I think this suggestion will reduce engagement a lot

Comment: completely agree with you Devin. my answer was based on the assumption and strong hope that there is some context before the modal is displayed.